# Filtro muestra registro aunque no sean del id indicado

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Tengo esta query pero solo busca por un solo dato, si quiero que me busque  tanto el id 193 como el id 191 u otro id, como podria hacerlo?, ademas que solo me muestre los id 164 ya que tambien me muestra de otros id que cumplen la condicion, pero solo necesito los 164

> NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) IN ('164', '193')

```html
  SELECT TRUNC (B.FECHA_CAPTURA)      AS RECEPCION_DCL,
         TRUNC (CREATE_DATE)          AS RECEPCION_CSC,
         DEC_DICT,
         NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) AS DEC_CSC,
         COUNT (*)                    AS AFORO,
         SUM (AMOUNT_REAL)            AS IMPORTE_CSC,
         SUM (AMOUNT_CHARGED)         AS IMPORTE_DCL
    FROM AMS_TRANSACTION A
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_DCL_CRUCES B ON ID_CRUCES = IDCRUCES
   WHERE     CREATE_DATE > :FECHA - (1 / (24 * 3600))
         AND CREATE_DATE < :FECHA + 1
         AND NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) IN ('164', '193')
         AND ID_CONCESSIONAIRE > 0         
GROUP BY TRUNC (B.FECHA_CAPTURA),
         TRUNC (CREATE_DATE),
         DEC_DICT,
         NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente consulta debieses tener los resultados esperados, aunque de NO ser así tu problema esta en la evaluación de las condiciones AND & OR

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC (B.FECHA_CAPTURA)        AS RECEPCION_DCL,
    TRUNC (CREATE_DATE)            AS RECEPCION_CSC,
    DEC_DICT                       AS DEC_DICT,
    NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) AS DEC_CSC,
    COUNT (*)                      AS AFORO,
    SUM (AMOUNT_REAL)              AS IMPORTE_CSC,
    SUM (AMOUNT_CHARGED)           AS IMPORTE_DCL
FROM AMS_TRANSACTION A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_DCL_CRUCES B ON ID_CRUCES = IDCRUCES
WHERE     CREATE_DATE > :FECHA - (1 / (24 * 3600))
    AND CREATE_DATE < :FECHA + 1
    AND (NVL(ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) = '164' OR NVL(ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT) IN ('193','191'))
    AND ID_CONCESSIONAIRE > 0         
GROUP BY 
    TRUNC (B.FECHA_CAPTURA),
    TRUNC (CREATE_DATE),
    DEC_DICT,
    NVL (ID_DECENA, ID_DECENA_EXT)
```

Comment: me sigue trayendo un resutado de mas que corresponde a un ID 165 y no 164

Comment: de la query original que coloque, le agregue en las condiciones del where la linea: AND B.DEC_DICT='164' y si trae solo los del ID 164, pero no se si afecte